# How can I install modules in Mac OS Terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, bots, telegram

I want to install some modules for *Telegram* Bots and I always get errors like:

```
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
  import spotipy
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'
```

I tried to install *spotipy* with pip, pip3 and apt.
How is it done? Or generally how do I import modules?

Thank you.

Comment: Error messages?

Answer (score 1):

From [the spotipy README](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/README.md):

> If you already have Python on your system you can install the library simply by downloading the distribution, unpack it and install in the usual fashion:
>
> `python setup.py install`
>
> You can also install it using a popular package manager with
>
> `pip install spotipy`
>
> or
>
> `easy_install spotipy`

Make sure your pip version matches your python version (`pip --version` and `python --version` should both be Python3 or Python2).

To import the module, use one of the following statements (see [python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)):

```py
import numpy
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
```